# Can we have both href and ng-click in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a text box:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="SearchText" >
```

And a link:

```
<a href="#signout" ng-click="SearchText=''">Sign out</a>
```

I want to exectue both in the above hyperlink. `ng-click` to empty text-box and `#signout` will `ng-route` to signout HTML and controller.

But I can see href overrides `ng-click` in Angular.js

How to execute both?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue: http://jsbin.com/luyinojade/1/edit

Comment: Another option is you can also write function in ng-click which will clear text-box and change URL with $location.

Comment: @ChiragB What would that function look like if you wanted to change the url to any URL such as google.com?

Comment: @IanSteffy $window.location.href = 'https://www.google.co.in';

Comment: My use-case is that i want to view a PDF on click and also trigger a function to note that the user has clicked it.

Answer (score 9):

If you use `ng-mouseup` or `ng-mousedown` depending on when you need the event to fire it will not override `ng-href` like `ng-click` does.

```
<a ng-href="#signout" ng-mouseup="SearchText=''">Sign out</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) here with anchor tag.

```
<a ng-href="#signout" ng-click="SearchText=''">Sign out</a>
```

You can use ng-click with this too.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/atTEvb2K8ZrEus9nqOsS?p=preview)

Comment: It is not related to that :-P

Comment: Here href and ng-click also works fine. first click event executes and then anchor tag will make request.

Comment: This solution and demo does not work. ng-click is called and then we are sent to an error page that has nothing to do with the link. When this solution is used in my own example, like this example **only** ng-click is called and ng-href is ignored.